# Sphinxsearch не считается вес

Tags: sphinx, sphinxsearch

Помогите понять, пожалуйста, как считается weight?

Не могу поднять наверх результаты по значению атрибута.
Атрибут - целое число, в настройках индекса указан тип int

```
OPTION ranker=expr('IF(IN(brand_id, 45935), 1000, 5)')
```

Ничего не происходит, по результатам выборки weight() всегда 1.

PS. Выборка без ранкера корректна, поле brand_id заполнено корректно, вот [тут](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/expression-ranker.html)
указано что это возможно.

Answer (score 0):

В Sphinx не пробовал, а в Manticore (https://manticoresearch.com/) всё работает и с вашим вариантом и с просто IF(a=N,...) :

```
mysql> select *, weight() from rt where match('abc') option ranker=expr('(if(brand_id=45935,1000,5))');
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | brand_id | weight() |
+------+----------+----------+
|    1 |    45935 |     1000 |
|    3 |    45935 |     1000 |
|    2 |      234 |        5 |
+------+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, weight() from rt where match('abc') option ranker=expr('if(in(brand_id,45935),1000,5)');
+------+----------+----------+
| id   | brand_id | weight() |
+------+----------+----------+
|    1 |    45935 |     1000 |
|    3 |    45935 |     1000 |
|    2 |      234 |        5 |
+------+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Возможно в той версии Sphinx, которую вы используете баг. Переезжайте на Manticore.